# Mocking console.log()/Any Other Function in MOCHA testing framework

Tags: javascript, mocking, mocha.js, sinon

I am writing test cases for NODE JS API. But wherever `console.log()` is there in routes or services of NODE JS File, it gets printed to CLI. Is there a way to mock these so that these won't get printed in CLI.

I have explored couple of libraries like Sinon, Stub for mocking. But couldn't grasp the working of those libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You can override function entirely: `console.log = function () {}`.

Comment: But Is there a way to mock console.log? I think that will be best solution for writing test cases.

Comment: This is mocking console.log. What do you have in mind when you say "mock"?

Comment: Mocking in writing test cases means, I don't want that function to execute but I can give any input and get output also. Mocking DB connection, API calls. hope you understood.

Comment: Ok, we are on the same page. The thing is - you can give this dummy function any input and output of original console.log (and this dummy) is always _undefined_. So it meets all of your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to mock console.log itself, a better approach is for your node modules to take a logging object. This allows you to provide an alternative (ie. a mock) during testing. For example:

```
<my_logger.js>
module.exports = {
    err: function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}

<my_module.js>
var DefaultLogger = require('my_logger.js');

module.exports = function(logger) {
    this.log = logger || DefaultLogger;
    // Other setup goes here
};

module.exports.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    this.log.err('Error message.');
};

<my_module_test.js>
var MyModule = require('my_module.js');

describe('Test Example', function() {
    var log_mock = { err: function(msg) {} };

    it('Should not output anything.', function() {
        var obj = new MyModule(log_mock);
        obj.myMethod();
    });
});
```

The code here I've simplified, as the actual test isn't the reason for the example. Merely the insertion of alternative logging.

If you have a large codebase with lots of console.log calls, it is better to simply update the code as you add tests for each method. Making your logging pluggable in this way makes your code easier and more receptive to testing. Also, there are many logging frameworks available for node. console.log is fine during development when you just want to dump out something to see what's going on. But, if possible, try to avoid using it as your logging solution.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution which **only** hides the `console.log` calls in the module to be tested, and mocks **none** of the calls of the testing framework (mocha/chai in my case).

I came up with using a copy of `console` in the app code:

```
/* console.js */
module.exports = console;

/* app.js */
const console = require('./console');
console.log("I'm hidden in the tests");

/* app.spec.js */
const mockery = require('mockery');
var app;

before(() => {
  // Mock console
  var consoleMock = {
    log: () => {}
  }
  mockery.registerMock('./console', consoleMock);
  // Require test module after mocking
  app = require('./app');
});

after(() => {
  mockery.deregisterAll();
  mockery.disable();
});

it('works', () => {});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something along the lines of adding these before/after blocks to your tests, but the issue is that mocha actually uses console.log to print the pretty messages about the results of the test, so you would lose those

```
describe('Test Name', function() {
  var originalLog;
  beforeEach(function() {
    originalLog = console.log;
    console.log = function () {};
  });
  // test code here
  afterEach(function() {
    console.log = originalLog;
  })
})
```

The problem is that your output would just look like

```
  Test Name


  X passing (Yms)
```

Without any intermediate text

Comment: can we use libraries like sinon, stub to mock these?